# Use intermediate value on ode MATLAB solver

Tags: matlab, ode

I am doing a time integration of a system of ODEs using a stiff solver (ode15s). It is working, but I want to speed things up.

The system of equations is given in state space form:

```
function [dx] = fun(t,x,M,C,K,other_parameters)
    % Mx'' + Cx' + Kx = F(t)
    % BUNCH OF CALCULATIONS
    F = solveP(x,t);

    A = [zeros(n) eye(n) ; -M\K -M\C];
    b = M\F;

    dx = A*x + b
end
```

The trick part here is the forcing function F. It is highly nonlinear and depends on the x and t parameters. It uses the x parameters to solve a Poisson-type 2D equation (by the Finite Volume method). The force F is proportional to the Poisson equation solution.

```
function [F] = solveP(x,t)
    % initialize solution
    Phi = zeros(Ni,Nj);

    % solve iteratively
    % ...
    while (~converged)
         % some calculations

         % iterative solver
         Phi(i,j) = (aE*Phi(i,j+1) + aW*Phi(i,j-1) + aN*Phi(i+1,j) +...
                     aS*Phi(i-1,j) + S(i,j))/aP;
    end


    % calculate F
    F = sum(Phi(:)); % discrete integration over domain
end
```

Solving the Poisson equation by a iterative method requires an initial condition, which I set to zero (`Phi=zeros(Ni,Nj)`). I thought I could improve the speed of calculations by providing a better initial estimative of the ϕ field (a better initial condition would take faster to reach the sought answer). The optimal initial condition I can think (besides ϕ=0) is the value of the ϕ field obtained in the previous iteration (the last step) of the ode solver (`ϕ(k)_initial=ϕ(k-1)`).

Bottom line is: how do I use/save intermediate values in the ode solution?

PS: I tried using the persistent variables, but that is not a good solution. The ode solver calculates the function in several points before advancing in time. The persistent variable saves the converged ϕ field every time the ode calls the odefun fun. That is not exactly what I want and this actually provides wrong answers as time marching goes on.

Comment: From what you show of `solveP`, `F` is only dependent on the number of iterations (and thus not on `x`). If that is the case, why not first determine `Phi` for the required number of iterations, then the `cumsum` gives `F` for every time step. So this would just be a lookup table. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you looking for the method to save `F` variable, the same as you save `dx`? Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: @rinkert actually `F` is dependent on `x`. Changed the code to show that. The code is more extensive than that. The Poisson-type equation is a [diffusion equation](http://www-eng.lbl.gov/~shuman/NEXT/MATERIALS&COMPONENTS/Xe_damage/diffusion_eq.pdf). The dependency of the equation with the `x` variable appears both in the diffusion coefficient and the source term. I solve the diffusion equation by a finite voluem method (in this particular case, the final equations are equal to a finite difference discretization of the partial differential equation).

Comment: @Karls yes. As the time marches, the differences of subsequente Phi fields are not too big. Since I solve the discretized form of the pde by an iterative method, if I could provide a better initial estimative for the Phi field (instead of initializing with zeros in every ode iteration), I believe I could save some time. If I were to write an ode solver, I could pass is it as input and output arguments - but I will never be able to write an ode solver nearly as good as MATLAB's solvers.

Answer (score 0):

A possible fix is to write the found solution for `Phi` to the base workspace after one iteration. First you have to initialize `Phi` in the base workspace:

```
Phi = zeros(Ni, Nj);
```

Then you can just recall this `Phi` in the `solveP` function by using [`evalin`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalin.html). Then after you found an updated solution for `Phi`, be sure to assign it again in the base workspace using [`assignin`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html). `solveP` would then look like this:

```
function [F] = solveP(x,t)
    % initialize solution
    Phi = evalin('base','Phi');

    % solve iteratively
    % ...
    while (~converged)
         % some calculations

         % iterative solver
         Phi(i,j) = (aE*Phi(i,j+1) + aW*Phi(i,j-1) + aN*Phi(i+1,j) +...
                     aS*Phi(i-1,j) + S(i,j))/aP;
    end


    % calculate F
    F = sum(Phi(:)); % discrete integration over domain

    % assign updated Phi in base workspace
    assignin('base', 'Phi2', Phi)
end
```